# position div on the left side of main content

Tags: css, css-float

I am struggling with correct positioning of the DIV on the picture. It uses JS to scroll up and down which works fine. The problem is, I can't resize the window of my browser. In this case the DIV is covering the content of the page.

[image: DIV on the left]

CSS of the DIV:

```
#topbar_right{
position:absolute;
margin-top: -5px;
z-index: 2;
right:50%;
margin-right:100px;
}
```

My question is: How can I position this div so its right edge always stays at the same place and it does not cover the content when I resize the window.

Thank you for your responses!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using position: absolute instead of floating it left?

Comment: Its nearly impossible to help without a link or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) based on your question

Comment: @Adrift: 'nearly impossible' is a bit of an overstatement.  While either of those would help, it's certainly possible to answer questions without them.

Comment: Before posting a link *or* a JSFiddle, put your markup here.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal flow of the document.

If you are forced to use absolute positioning on the `DIV`, you can apply `left-margin` to the content block, equal to width of the absolutely positioned `DIV`.